# java collections: Filter using mapped values and then return to initial values

Tags: java, collections, java-8

Is there a short and elegant way of reversing mapping function?

The problem goes like this: I have a bunch of objects of type A, which I need to map to type B, perform filtering on the B objects, and then return back to corresponding A objects.

To provide some specifics and an example:
I have a bulk filtering function

```
Collection<CarVO> myFilter(Collection<CarVO> originalCollection);
```

and a `Collection<Car> cars`, and finally a mapping method `Car#toVO()`.
I came up with this code:

```
Collection<Car> filtered = cars.stream()
    .filter(car -> !myFilter(Collections.singleton(car)).isEmpty())
    .collect(toList());
```

but I suspect this is not efficient because I filter objects one by one.
Other way to do the same thing:

```
Map<Car, CarVO> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Car car : cars) map.put(car, car.toVO());
Collection<CarVO> filteredVOs = myFilter(map.values());
cars = cars.stream.filter(car -> filteredVOs.contains(map.get(car))).collect(toList());
```

But I don't fancy building map explicitly.

UPD: Thank you all,
Didn't know that `Map.values()` returned a live view. I'll stick to using `retainAll()` then.

Comment: I did not understand your efficiency concern with your first solution.  Have you benchmarked it to verify your assumption?

Comment: You will want to post a simplified version of `CarVO`, `myFilter` and `Car` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your method `myFilter(Collection<CarVO>)` must make a decision about whether each element should be removed or not, and you assume this to work even for a single-element collection, it must be possible to extract the logic into a single-item `Predicate`. Using that extracted predicate would be the most efficient solution.

But if you can’t do that and are for whatever reason bound to using this existing method, you may use it as follows:

```
Map<Car, CarVO> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Car car: cars) map.put(car, car.toVO());
map.values().retainAll(myFilter(map.values()));
Set<Car> filtered=map.keySet();
```

If you really need a list, you may replace the last line with

```
List<Car> filtered=new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
```

Note that this assumes that `myFilter` returns a new collection. If it applies the filter directly to its collection parameter by removing elements from it, you may replace `map.values().retainAll(myFilter(map.values()));` with `myFilter(map.values());`

Comment: It cannot remove the elements directly from the input collection. Otherwise passing `Collections.singleton()` would result in `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: you are right, so my assumption can be called a “founded assumption”, however, I’ll still prefer to mention that the solution is built on assumptions. For my taste, there’s still too little information about `myFilter`, what it does and why it has to be a bulk filter rather than a single element predicate…

Comment: I can speculate that it passes the request to some backend system (DBMS, web API) which may perform bulk-processing. In this case you may have too much overhead processing each element separately. Of course this is also *assumption*.

Comment: Thanks! If i build map explicitly, then there is no problem, I'll stick to that than.

Comment: Current implementation of `myFilter` can be split into foreach loop and a predicate, but Tagir's point is why i want to call `myFilter` only once, thus possibly avoiding planting a mine for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) for a single Car?

In the Predicate you could transform a car in a CarVO (if necessary) and then apply the logic for the single element.

And for the the sake of the DRY principle you should use this predicate inside the original myFilter method.

Comment: thank you, this helps in my case, but i am concerned with Tagir's point.